# Did Kwenthrith have all of the drinks poisoned in Season 3 episode 4?

Tags: vikings

In Vikings, after Kwenthrith's brother dies, everyone pours out their wine.
Were all of the drinks poisoned (or was everyone simply put off)? I find this unlikely, as when the scene opens, time seems to have already passed (i.e. they hadn't just congregated), and would everybody really have held their drinks in their hands for so long without taking a sip? Of course, we don't actually see anybody else take  a sip.

Have I missed something?

Also- on the side- was that a bit of brother-sister romance going on, when Kewenthirth and her brother kept touching each other and declaring each other's love (and also judging by the look on Ecbert's and Ragnar's face).

Answer (score 3):

## Kwenthrith suspected that her brother was after the throne.

She poisoned her brother's drink because she wanted the throne and the power. She certainly had motives for it.

She also liked Ragnar in a romantic way. She went after him when he was injured.

[image]

> She peed on his wounds. Obvious that she cares for him.

In the later episodes, it is revealed later that she was carrying Ragnar's child and gave birth to a boy.

She wouldn't poison Ragnar's drink. As a result, maybe some of those drinks were poisoned but not Ragnar's was (IMO).